# How to read number count of words?

Tags: tcl

How  to read number count of words?

Lines has this format:

```
vertices_count
X, Y
X, Y
X, Y
```

(X, Y pair can be in the same line)

for example:

```
3
12.5, 56.8
12.5, 56.8
12.5, 56.8
```

I would like to read vertices_count number of words(escaping comma):

So for above example reading words should be:

```
12.5 56.8 12.5 56.8 12.5 56.8
```

Comment: This is a little too elliptical for me. Please can you clarify your question by stating explicitly some typical inputs with desired outputs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set fh [open f r]
gets $fh num
read $fh data
close $fh

set number_re {-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?|-?\d*\.\d+}
set vertices {}
foreach {_ x y} [regexp -inline -all "($number_re),\\s*($number_re)" $data] {
    lappend vertices $x $y
    if {[llength $vertices] == $num * 2} break
}
puts $vertices
# => 12.5 56.8 12.5 56.8 12.5 56.8
```

---

```
while {[llength $vertices] < $num * 2} {
    gets $fh line
    foreach {_ x y} [regexp -inline -all "($number_re),\\s*($number_re)" $line] {
        lappend vertices $x $y
        if {[llength $vertices] == $num * 2} break
    }
}
close $fh
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not clear *exactly* what you are after. Here is some code to read data from a named file. Judging from your other question, you can have several sets of data in your input stream and this code returns them all as a list. Each element of the list is one set of coordinates

```
# Read the input from file

set fil [open filename.file]
set input [read $fil]
close $fil

set data [list];                # No output so for
set seekCount yes;              # Next token is a vertex count

foreach token [string map {, " "} $input] {
                                # Convert commas to spaces
    if {$seekCount} {
        set nCoords [expr $token * 2];
                                # Save number of coordinates
        set datum [list];       # Clean out vertex buffer
    } else {
        lappend datum $token;   # Save coordinate
        incr nCoords -1
        if {$nCoords <= 0} {
                                # That was the last coordinate
            lappend data $datum; # Append the list of coordinates
            set seekCount yes;  # and look for anopther count
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very quick-and-dirty solution, which makes no attempt to handle errors. One thing, however that it will cope with is variable amounds of whitespace and missing whitespace after the commas.

Good luck, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This procedure first reads a count line, then reads that number of lines and puts as a list into $varName. It returns the number of elements in $varName, or -1 if EOF occured before a count was read.

```
proc getNLines {stream varName} {
  upvar 1 $varName lines

  set lines {}
  if {[gets $stream n] < 0} {
    return -1
  }
  while {$n > 0} {
    if {[gets $stream line] < 0} {
      error "bad data format"
    }
    lappend lines $line
    incr n -1
  }
  return [llength $lines]
}

while {[getNLines stdin lines] >= 0} {
  # ...
}
```